# Nodejs Mysql connection pooling using mysql module

Tags: mysql, database, node.js, node-mysql

We are using mysql module for node and i was just wondering if this approach is good or does it have any bad effects on our application, consider this situation

```
dbPool.getConnection(function(err, db) {
    if(err) return err;
    db.query()
```

Here i am calling the dbPool object and requesting a connection from the pool then using it. However i found another implementation (which is the one i am asking about) which uses the dbPool object directly like:

```
dbPool.query('select * from test where id = 1' function(err, rows) {})
```

so i was wondering what does the second implementation does exactly, does it automatically return a free connection and use it ? can explain what is happening exactly in the second case and if it has any effect + or - on my application ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So this is so what called callback chaining. In NodeJS you have a lot of asynchronous calls going around. But sometimes you want to do something when the connection is done with MySQL. That's why the `getConnection` functionality has a `callBack` feature.

```
dbPool.getConnection(function(err, db) {
    if(err) return err;
    db.query()
```

Is equal to this:

```
dbPool.query('select * from test where id = 1' function(err, rows) {})
```

`dbPool.query()` will wait for the connection to be open,  you don't have to put all your queries inside the getConnection to make it work. This is why it also has a callBack feature.

Tell me if I'm wrong. I hope this solves your question.

Comment: actually its working fine there are no problems but i was talking about the implementation itself i mean the pool object(dbPool) is made in order to return for you a free connection to mysql in which you could use it to query the db but how could i use the pool object itself without waiting for it to return a free connection ?

Comment: It is better to use one connection yes, but this will give you less flexibility in querying the database, because you can only do it when you have the connection open.